# How can I change the password on Stack Overflow effectively?

Tags: bug, login, accounts

It looks like that my password won't get stored in Stack Overflow. Every time I want to log into Stack Overflow, a message appears stating that my password is wrong. I can change it, but it won't get stored. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: That is for a stack exchange account, right?

Comment: Hmm, something similar was reported in 2018, no fix but a workaround in the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316883/cant-change-password

Comment: Could you describe the process you are using to change your password?

Comment: @DavyM Sure. I want to login, fill in the credentials, the response shows an incorrect login, then I chose to change my password, fill in my email address, navigate to the password change link inside the mail and enter a new password. 

When I log out now, because I am already logged in, the error message stays, stating the entered password was invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stackoverflow seems not to handle too well with old emails. I changed mine, received notifications and the like, even password reset links. However, log in only works with my old email. That actually does the trick. Is this a bug in stackoverflow or am I just missing a certain setting ?

Comment: Changing emails hasn't worked well at least since I joined 4 years ago. There's also a lot of weird behavior, like SE OpenID being discontinued, but still exists and you register as logged in even if you've migrated to the new system. Area51 also accesses a separate email field from v2 or whatever the official name is. TL;DR: it's a mess.

Comment: After knowing this, I would call it a minor annoyance. Would be nice, if this would somehow be fixed in near future, or at least old data garbage could be cleared.

Comment: It has been like this for a few years. There's a lot we'd like to be fixed in general, and I think they're aware of it, but it's a complex issue from what I can tell. In the meanwhile, all we can do is find workarounds.

Comment: that's for sure.